# Not sure why this Radio Button is throwing an error?

Tags: c#, database, radio-button, dataset, messagebox

I am currently making a fitness class booking system for some study I am doing so please bare with me.

I have done most of the code but I am having this strange issue with my 2nd radio button for selecting what class you want.

I have set up my code so a message box appears if the Member ID you have entered is already registered to the fitness class you have selected. For my RadioButton1 (rbCardioClass) and RadioButton2 (rbPilatesClass), the error message box works great and works as it should. But my RadioButton2 (rbSpinClass) will make the error message box appear everytime, even if the MemberID is not associated to the 'Spin Class'.

I have tried different uses of if statements, different radio buttons etc but can't seem to get it to work the way I want.

If I go to my `servicesErrorCheck(string[] description)`method and just the `temp` variable to `true` all radio buttons save to the database table correctly BUT I then lose my erroring, which makes me thinks it is something to do with the way I have set up the message box, maybe.

Here is a screenshot of the prototype form just for reference. [FitnessClassBooking Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMqB.png)

Here is a screenshot of the table while the app is running [App Running Fitness Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VyQc.png)

Here is the error being thrown with MemberID that has no 'Spin' class associated with it [App Running Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpmbB.png)

Here is my code in question -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Membership_Formv2
{
public partial class FitnessClassBooking : Form
{
    public FitnessClassBooking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new MainMenu().Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void fitnessInformationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.fitnessInformationBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.databaseDataSet);

    }

    private void FitnessClassBooking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'databaseDataSet.Members' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.membersTableAdapter.Fill(this.databaseDataSet.Members);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.fitnessInformationTableAdapter.Fill(this.databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation);



    }

    private void fitnessInformationDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private string descriptionfit()
    {

        string className = "";

       

        if (rbCardioClass.Checked == true)
        {
            className = "Cardio";
        }
        else if (rbSpinClass.Checked == true)
        {
            className = "Spin";
        }
        else if (rbPilatesClass.Checked == true)
        {
            className = "Pilates";
        }

        return className;

    }

    private string classDescription()
    {
        string serviceSeletionString = "Class";

        if (rbCardioClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbCardioClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
        else if (rbSpinClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbSpinClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
        else if (rbPilatesClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbPilatesClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }

        return serviceSeletionString;
    }

    private bool errorCheckingID()
    {
        bool statusDB = true;
        //Getting row info from MembersTa table
        DatabaseDataSet.MembersRow newEntry = databaseDataSet.Members.FindByMemberID(Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text));

        //Getting information from BookingTa table
        if (newEntry == null)
        {
            statusDB = false;
            return (statusDB);
        }
        return (statusDB);
    }


    public bool servicesErrorCheck(string[] description)
    {
        bool temp = true;
        string serviceSeletionString = "";

        if (rbCardioClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbCardioClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
        else if (rbSpinClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbSpinClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }
        else if (rbPilatesClass.Checked == true)
        {
            serviceSeletionString = rbPilatesClass.Text;
            this.Refresh();
        }


        for (int t = 0; t < description.Length; t++)
        {
            if (serviceSeletionString.Contains(description[t].Trim()))
            {
                temp = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return (temp);
    }

    private string originalaccesdb()
    {
        string a = "";

        DatabaseDataSet.FitnessInformationRow newRow = databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.NewFitnessInformationRow();

        newRow.Fitness_Booking_ID = databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.Count + 1;
        newRow.Description = descriptionfit();
        newRow.MemberID = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.AddFitnessInformationRow(newRow);

        return a;
    }

    private string[] accessDB()
    {
        int t = 0;
        int temp;
        string[] servicesList = { "n", "n", "n" };  //This variable will store the data

        //Same code too extract table information
        foreach (DataRow r in databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.Rows)
        {
            temp = Int32.Parse(r["MemberID"].ToString());

            if (temp == Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text))
            {
                //Store inside the array all the services/description against the ID.
                //Note that this array will remain "" for all the elements inside the array
                //if no descritopn/services (i.e., record) is found against the input ID
                servicesList[t] = r["Description"].ToString();
                t = t + 1;
            }
        }
        return (servicesList);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        

        string text = textBox1.Text;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        int a = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        DatabaseDataSet.MembersRow newID = databaseDataSet.Members.FindByMemberID(Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));

        string booking = "";
        int temp;

        foreach (DataRow r in databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.Rows)
        {
            temp = Int32.Parse(r["MemberID"].ToString());

            if (temp == Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text))
            {
                booking = r["Description"].ToString() + ", " + booking;
            }
        }

        textBox1.Text = "Member ID is: " + (newID.MemberID).ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "First Name is: " + (newID.First_Name).ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Last Name is: " + (newID.Last_Name).ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Bookings: " + booking;

        
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        bool status1, status2;
        string[] description;

        //Error control at the outer level for valid ID
        status1 = errorCheckingID();

        //Proceed only if ID is valid or status1 is true
        if (status1)
        {
            //Retrieve information from the other database. Ideally you want this method to return
            //an array containing registered services. This would be an array of strings.
            description = accessDB();

            //Services error checking
            status2 = servicesErrorCheck(description);

            //Now this is the code that would call the method to save data ito database
            //when status2 and 2 are true
            if (status2)
            {

                //Code for saving into database. 
                DatabaseDataSet.FitnessInformationRow newRow = databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.NewFitnessInformationRow();

                newRow.Fitness_Booking_ID = databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.Count + 1;
                newRow.Description = classDescription();
                newRow.MemberID = Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                databaseDataSet.FitnessInformation.AddFitnessInformationRow(newRow);
            }
            else
            {
                //Show error that this service is not available
                MessageBox.Show("This Class is already assigned to that Member ID");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Error message invalid ID
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID");
        }
    }

    private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        }
    }
}
```

I am really not sure why this is happening so I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking each string in `descriptions` as follows:

```
serviceSeletionString.Contains(description[t].Trim())
```

which considering at least one of the strings is just `n` it will always match `Spin`.
Quite why you are always returning an array with the blank ones having `n`, I don't know. Personally I would just use a `List<string>` and `Add` each item from the database to it. But that is a separate point.

Either change it to `serviceSeletionString == description[t]` (don't see why you need `Trim()`) or just replace the whole `foreach` loop with `description.Contains(serviceSeletionString)`

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the advice, much appreciated. I tried to add the code you advised above and all though they let me add the new records into the database, it does not error anymore if a 'memberID' is already associated with a 'class'... Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `databaseDataSet.SaveChanges()` maybe? You need to debug this step by step, and verify at all points that variables are the way you expect them to be. I can't run your code, I'm just noticing things that pop out.

Comment: Okay thanks @charlieface. I will keep looking.